# C# .IndexOf(char,int) return incorrect value

Tags: c#, indexof

I need to get index of second '.' in e-mail adres.
a)

```
string email =john.curter@it.dev.comp.com ;
int dotIndex = email.IndexOf('.');
int nextDotIndex = email.IndexOf('.',dotIndex);
```

result

```
nextDotIndex == 4
```

If i make that like this:
b)

```
string email =john.curter@it.dev.comp.com ;
int dotIndex = email.IndexOf('.');
int nextDotIndex = email.IndexOf('.',dotIndex+1);
```

result

```
nextDotIndex == 14
```

I know that in a) first checked element is index of first '.',but

**Why  in a) nextDotIndex==4, not nextDotIndex ==0 ?**

Comment: Why would it be `0`? The method returns the index in the *string*, not from the offset. The official docs state as much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why in a) nextDotIndex==4, not nextDotIndex ==0 ?

becuase you did

```
int nextDotIndex = email.IndexOf('.', 4);
```

on this string

```
john.curter@it.dev.comp.com
0123456789
```

you said start at offset 4, which is the '.'

`Indexof` returns the offset in the whole string, not the offset relative to the start

from the 'manual' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-char-system-int32)

> Returns
> Int32
> The zero-based index position of value from the start of the string if that character is found, or -1 if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, for the second check, it's starting looking at index 4, it checks that character, and behold, it has found the character, so it goes to return it, and it tells you what index in the string it found it at. It didn't find it at index zero, it found it at index 4. Just because it didn't check the lower numbered indexes doesn't mean they don't exist.

This is the expected behavior, you can see it in the documentation:

[Documentation for String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

string index starts from 0.

```
string email = "john.curter@it.dev.comp.com;";
int dotIndex = email.IndexOf("."); // 4

email.Substring(dotIndex); // .curter@it.dev.comp.com;
```

So you have to add 1, otherwise you will start from dot

```
 int nextDotIndex = email.IndexOf('.',dotIndex+1); //14
```

Answer (score 0):

`int index = s.IndexOf(',', s.IndexOf(',') + 1);`
You may ensure that you're not going outofbound

Answer (score -1):

```cs
using System.Linq;
var email = "abc.d.ef@gh.com";
int n = 2; // the nIndex you want example 2 => 5
var tableSplit = email.Split('.');  //split by dot
var before =string.Join('.', tableSplit.Take(n)); // your rebuid precedent string  'abc.d' 
int nIndex = before.Length;// 5
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).